# Are there any requirements for constructor's arguments in Java

Tags: java, constructor

Usually, the costructor is like below

```
private int occurence;
private String content;
public Word(String content,int occurence)
{
   this.content= content;
   this.occurence = occurence;
}
```

But can I set the parameters that not directly be assigned to the attributes but are required to calculate the value of attributes?

For example, there is a method in **Article** class called **calOccurence(String content)** that can calculate occurence based on the article. So can I build the construtor like this??

```
public Word(String content, Article base)
{
   this.content= content;
   this.occurence = base.calOccurence(content);
}
```

And what if the **calOccurence** function belongs to **Word** class, like **calOccurence(String content, Article base)** ?

```
public Word(String content, Article base)
{
   this.content= content;
   this.occurence = this.calOccurence(content, base);
}
```

It looks strange but my teammate write codes like the above. I wonder whether it's reasonable?

Comment: Note that your ctor code is explicitly *not* the same as your co-workers in that you try to call `calOccurence` on an `Article` rather than the `Word` instance being constructed. The only thing "strange" about your co-worker's ctor is that it doesn't use the instance's `content` property, instead passing in the ctor parameter--but that isn't intrinsically strange. Ultimately you can pass whatever you want into a constructor.

Comment: That's legal, although that example is not a reasonable design, IMO: `calOccurence` looks like a potentially expensive operation, and a `Word` looks like an object you'd want to create many instances of; each time you do `new Word`, you'd be scanning the content once per word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the occurrence of a word cannot exist without an Article, I think it's best to leave out the occurrence field from the Word class and only use that in the Article class.

Something like this

```
public class Word {
    String text;
    Article article;

    public Word(String text, Article article) {
        this.text = text;
        this.article = article;
    }

    // other code
}

public class Article
    String content;
    public Article(String content) {
        this.content = content;   
    }

    public int calOccurrence(Word word) {
        // Calculate the occurrence of word.text in this.content
    }

    // other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor should always ensure that the resulting object is completely initialized and ready to be used. Calling other methods within the class to do this work is perfectly acceptable, but you have to make sure that they can work with an object that is in an undefined state.

In your example, if the call to `this.calOccurence` happens before `this.content` is set, the `this.calOccurence` method still needs to work. This is why, instead of relying on the `this.content` variable, the method requires you to pass in the content value. Passing `content` as an argument instead of relying on the class' properties ensures that it will always have all the data it needs.

Now, if the number of occurrence is not always needed, it might be a better strategy to turn it into a lazy property and only calculate its value when it is needed.